# How to turn of JShint from angular generator grunt file?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

How best to we get the default grunt file from the angular generator to stop trying to use jshint?

I've tried playing with various settings but the file is so complex it keeps breaking the build.

Comment: Can you either include your `Gruntfile.js` or link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the `jshint` task.